# TypeError: Failed to fetch when using Filament Import Action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm new to Filament and Livewire and I'm trying to get the pre-built [Import Action](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/actions/prebuilt-actions/import) to work.

I have a CSV file which when imported, needs to create Attendees. This is my CSV structure:

```
"Name", "Linked To", "Relation" (string value), "Type guest", "Residence", "Telephone", "RSVP Sent" "RSVP day", "RSVP evening"
```

Which needs to fill these models/tables:

Attendee.php

```
class Attendee extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'attendee_id',
        'relation_id',
        'save_the_date_sent_at',
        'rsvp_sent_at',
        'rsvp_reminder_sent_at',
        'responded_at',
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'rsvp_day',
        'rsvp_evening',
        'language',
        'residence',
        'type',
        'notes',
    ];


    public function relation(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Relation::class);
    }

    public function childAttendees(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attendee::class, 'attendee_id', 'id');
    }

    public function mainAttendee(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Attendee::class, 'attendee_id');
    }
}
```

Relation.php:

```
class Relation extends Model
{
    ...

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function attendees(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attendee::class);
    }
}
```

In my `AttendeeImporter.php`, this is mapped like so:

```
public static function getColumns(): array
{
    return [
        ImportColumn::make('name')
            ->requiredMapping()
            ->rules(['required', 'max:255'])
            ->guess(['naam']),
        ImportColumn::make('attendee_id')
            ->label('Attendee')
            ->requiredMapping()
            ->relationship(resolveUsing: function (array $state): ?Attendee {
                return Attendee::where('name', $state)->first();
            })
            ->rules(['required', 'max:255'])
            ->guess(['Linked to']),
        ImportColumn::make('relation')
            ->relationship(resolveUsing: function (array $state): ?Relation {
                return Relation::firstOrCreate(['name' => $state]);
            }),
        ImportColumn::make('phone_number')
            ->rules(['max:255'])
            ->guess(['Telephone']),
        ImportColumn::make('residence')
            ->rules(['max:255'])
            ->guess(['Woonplaats']),
        ImportColumn::make('type')
            ->requiredMapping()
            ->rules(['required'])
            ->castStateUsing(function (string $state): ?string {
                if (blank($state)) {
                    \Log::info('cannot be null!');

                    return GuestType::DAY->name;
                }

                return GuestType::getFromSheet($state)->name;
            })
            ->guess(['type guest']),
    ];
}
```

When I log in to the admin panel and try to import a CSV file, the upload works. But when I actually try to import it (by pressing the import button), nothing happens and I see these 2 errors:

```
POST http://localhost/livewire/update net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

livewire.js?id=e2b302e9:4141 
        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at sendRequest
```

Anyone got some pointers?

Comment: Hi @pu4cu did you find any solution. same problem here

Comment: Hi @JosephProsper, yes the error was due to my CSV which had incorrect or unexpected data. If you need help, you can show me your code and csv and I can take a look